# Import doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a wierd problem.  There are two apps in my django project . In one app one of the imports made in views.py is fine but in the other one the same import shows me an error.

Here is views.py  where import is fine:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from models import Category,Product
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.core import urlresolvers
from cart import cart
from catalog.forms import ProductAddToCartForm
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
# Create your views here.

def index(request, template_name="catalog/index.html"):

    page_title = 'Extremely interesting and cheap goods'

    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))



def show_category(request,category_slug,template_name='catalog/category.html'):
    c = get_object_or_404(Category, slug = category_slug)
    products = c.product_set.all()
    page_title = c.name
    meta_keywords = c.meta_keywords
    meta_description = c.meta_description

    return render_to_response(template_name,locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))  



def show_product(request, product_slug,template_name="catalog/product.html"):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product,slug=product_slug) 
    categories = p.categories.all()
    page_title = p.name
    meta_keywords = p.meta_keywords
    meta_description = p.meta_description
    if request.method =='POST':
        postdata=request.POST.copy()
        form = ProductAddToCartForm(request,postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            cart.add_to_cart(request)
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = ProductAddToCartForm(request = request,label_suffix=':')
    form.fields['product_slug'].widget.attrs['value'] = product_slug
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    return render_to_response("catalog/product.html",locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here is views.py where import doesn't work:

```
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from cart import cart

def show_cart(request,template_name="cart/cart.html"):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Remove':
            cart.remove_from_cart(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Update':
            cart.update_cart(request)
    cart_items = cart.get_cart_items(request)
    page_title = 'Shopping Cart'
    cart_subtotal = cart.cart_subtotal(request)
    return render_to_response(template_name,locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The import I am speaking about is : from cart import cart. The second views.py is in the same django app where cart.py I am trying to import

Comment: so you have 2 views in the same app?

Comment: whats the path of those `views` ? and how you know it doesn't work? show your error !

Comment: They are in the same project and in two different apps

Comment: For the first one : /home/alex/workspace/DjangoBookExample/catalog/views.py 
For the second one /home/alex/workspace/DjangoBookExample/cart/views.py

Comment: so whats your error?

Comment: @user2970627 I would like to point out in your question that `import` is working fine. It just doesn't work the way you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the module of first app in the second app in this way

lets say, you cart.py is in catalog app.

```
# in catalog views
from cart import cart
```

and

```
# in cart app
from catalog.cart import cart
```

or vice versa depending where your cart.py is

assuming that apps are registered in `INSTALLED_APPS` like

```
..
'catalog',
'cart',
...
```

Comment: if cart.py in cart app import should look like

    from cart import cart

Answer (score 0):

1. rename your cart.py to something like carts.py
2. remove cart.pyc
3. change your code and  imports to "carts" instead of "cart" where
   need

For ex:

```
from cart import carts 
carts.add_to_cart(request)
```

etc.